# Can someone help me with Pyspark streaming error: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
import sys

from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark import SparkContext
try:
    sc.stop()
except:
    pass
from pyspark import SparkConf

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    sc = SparkContext(appName="StreamingErrorCount");
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
    
    ssc.checkpoint("C:\\Users\\streaming")
    lines =ssc.socketTextStream(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))\
                  .filter(lambda word:"ERROR" in word)\
                  .map(lambda word: (word, 1))\
                  .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)

    counts.pprint()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Gives the error:

```
---> 22     lines =ssc.socketTextStream(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))
     23     counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))\
     24                   .filter(lambda word:"ERROR" in word)\

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

Comment: Hi , can you please paste the code and actual error in a more readable format

Comment: @AdityaVikramSingh i did edit it.please check

Answer (score 0):

The second command line argument cannot be cast to an integer. Check that you're passing in the correct values on the command line. I believe it should be a port number.

Comment: the above is the.py that i want stream while giving the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code it correct , the only issue is with the command line arguments you are passing to the script

If you are calling the python to run the script this is the command
replace localhost  with the actual server

and 2837 with actual port on which you want your spark streaming job to listen

```
python StreamingErrorCount.py "localhost" 2837
```

If you are trying to deploy it on a spark cluster you can use spark-submit

```
spark-submit StreamingErrorCount.py "localhost" 2837
```

If this doesn't resolve the issue please paste the actual command you are executing to run this script .